# Cypher: How to match node based on property and then set or add new nodes accordingly?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have a nodes with properties `prop1` and `prop2`.

I would like to add a new node according to the following logic:

If a node `n` satisfies `n.prop1=123` then set `n.prop2=b` to be `789`;

If no such node exists then add a `Node` with with `{prop1=123, prop2=789}`.

The problem with doing something like `Merge (n:Node {prop1:123, prop2:789})` is that if some node `(m:Node {prop1:123, prop2:11111})` exists, for example, then we will end up with two nodes satisfying `prop1=123`.

On the other hand, if I do `Match (n:Node) Where prop1=123 Set prop2=789` then this will do nothing if a no node with `prop1=123` exits.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` is still the answer, set the second value after the node has been matched or created :

```
MERGE (n:Node {prop1: 123})
SET n.prop2 = 789
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we execute a merge query, a node is either matched or created. Using on create and on the match, you can set properties for indicating whether the node is created or matched.

Syntax
Following is the syntax of OnCreate and OnMatch clauses.

```
MERGE (node:label {properties . . . . . . . . . . .}) 
ON CREATE SET property.isCreated ="true" 
ON MATCH SET property.isFound ="true"
```